# Proxy на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, proxy, telegram, прокси

Всем привет! Недавно начал заниматься python ом и возникла идея сделать телеграмм бота. Поставил прокси на Ubuntu и бот работал. Убрал прокси и не работает. Вопрос... Можно ли встроить прокси в код программы? Если можно то как?(Хотя бы теоретически)

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: @Vlad Я пока ничего не использую. Интересно возможно ли сделали кусок кода,который бы выполнял программу через прокси.

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy